# How to show selected table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show selected table rows in a table, I have created a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/tonymaloney1971/1wsvayuL/

I have tried various methods, but cannot sem to get it to hide the selected rows.  I am thinking it is the visible property on ?

```
$('#showSelected').click(function (event) {
});
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain it? I dont understand what you are expecting to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1wsvayuL/4/)**

```
$('#showSelected').click(function (event) {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).prop('checked')){
            $(this).closest('tr').hide();
        }
    });
});

$('#showAll').click(function (event) {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').closest('tr').show();
});
```

Comment: it's just the matter of practice, the more you try the better you get, I'm still practicing you know! ;)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#showSelected').click(function (event) {
   var tr= $("[type=checkbox]:checked").map(function(){       
    return  $(this).closest("tr").text();
    }).get();
});
```

OR simply you can use

```
 $("[type=checkbox]:checked").show();
```

Comment: @user142617 Actually what do u need , i dont understand ,but i selected tr which is checked